# How to find or get the fired java scripts in a website using HtmlUnit

Tags: javascript, java, htmlunit

This is my code, can any one help me in this.

Thanks in advance.

```
 public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        WebClient webClient = new WebClient(Browser.CHROME);
        webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
        HtmlPage currentPage = webClient.getPage("https://www.crowndodgechryslerjeep.com/");
        String javaScriptCode = "https://www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion_async.js";
        ScriptResult result = currentPage.executeJavaScript(javaScriptCode);
        webClient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    }
```

Comment: can any one help me in this

Comment: Maybe yes, but i'm too stupid to understand your problem. Can you please make more clear, why you are trying to execute some external script in the context of the retrieved page and what are your expectations. HtmlUnit works like a browser (without a ui); in general retrieving a page executes all the embedded/referenced javascript like browsers do.